# Help understanding notation in matrix transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, transformation

In my notes it's written that, for two basis $B={e_i}$ and $B'=e'_i$, the transformation rule is:

$e'_j = c^i{}_j e_i$

This I can understand, every vector of the $B'$ basis is a linear combination of vectors from the $B$ basis. But when written in matrix notation:

$\begin{pmatrix}
e'_1 &...&e'_2 
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
e_1&...&e_2 
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot C$

According to the definitions of $B$ and $B$, every $e_i$ and $e'_i$ is a basis vector. But how would we write this in a real scenario, where we would have to use the components of every vector? Would we just expand every $e_i$ into its column, something like:

$\begin{pmatrix}
e'^1_1 & ... &e'^1_n \\ 
 ...& ... & ...\\ 
 e'^m_1&...  & e'^m_n
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
e^1_1 &...  &e^1_n \\ 
 ...&...  &... \\ 
 e^m_1& ... &e^m_n 
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot C$

But if you wrote it this way, then every $e'_i$ wouldn't be a linear combination of each $e_i$, every component would be a linear combination of the components of $e_i$, which isn't the same.

So, how would you do it? I suppose an answer is that you can't do it all at once, and that you can only do it with each basis vector at a time. Is that the case?